# iOS UITabBar make 'fake' active tab?

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible for a UITabBar to change only the active tab icon?

Let's say I have 5 tabs, 1st is active. I now want to make 2nd icon active, without changing ANYTHING else as far as TabBar is concerned, just that icon.

Whenever I try to highlight the 2nd icon, the TabBar switches controllers, and if it doesn't (delegate override) the icon's doesn't change either. Is there any way I can keep a tab being active, while only the icon not being active?

Why am I asking this?

I have a "More" tab which I want to be a popover on top of the current tab being active (so the current tab would be in the background visible), yet the "More" tab should be highlighted for the duration of the popover (if I make the "More" tab active, TabBar will switch controllers). After the popover is gone, if no new tab is selected, I would return to the previous tab from the background.

I managed to do the desired behaviour without making the "More" active. Whenever I touch that icon, TabBar switches controllers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: It is always helpful to have some *code* in your question that readers can use to repro your issue.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you could achieve this by implementing: [`tabBarController(_:shouldSelect:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate/1621166-tabbarcontroller) method.

Here is what you should do:

**First:** in the first view controller make sure to implement:

```
tabBarController?.delegate = self
```

`viewDidLoad` would be appropriate place.

**Second:** implement `tabBarController(_:shouldSelect:)` in the first view controller:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if viewController is PopupViewController {
        // present your pop-up here... for example:
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .destructive, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true)

        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

At this point, tapping the the item for the `PopupViewController` won't do anything (even highlighting the button), however it presents the `alert` no matter which view controller is currently active.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. But this has nothing to do with changing the highlighted tab icon... that's what I'm interested in more... if you return false there, you get the popup, but the active tab icon would remain the one you were on already and is in the background.

Comment: I want the behaviour you presented in code, but the highlighted tab bar icon should be the popup as long as the popup is active. After all it makes sense, because the popup is on top of everything and it has user focus. But if I change that, then the background view controller will be switched to the popup and there is no more popup on top of previous tab.

Comment: @AlinLipan Then it would be a kind of broad solution. As an idea what you could do is to take a screenshot from the current active view controller, pass it to the Popup view controller and present the alert and once you have done with it just go back to (activate) the previous view controller.

Answer (score 2):

You could subclass `UITabBarController` and override the `selectedViewController` property like this:

```
class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override var selectedViewController: UIViewController? {
        get {
            return super.selectedViewController
        }
        set {
            if newValue != viewControllers?.last {
                super.selectedViewController = newValue
            }
        }
    }

    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        if let tabBarItemIndex = tabBar.items?.firstIndex(of: item) {
            print("did select tab bar item at index \(tabBarItemIndex)")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think this will highlight the last tab icon, while keeping the previous view controller behind the new popover one.

Comment: It will. Just try.

Comment: Ok, I'm giving it a try.

Comment: I tested it, and it works, partially... it highlights the last item, yet keeping the previous. But now I'm having problems presenting the popover. If I add a child view controller inside shouldSelect to be the popover, the background turns black weirdly. I'll do some more testing and come back when I succeed (hopefully).

Comment: I now understood what you did there, that's really smart. That was the workaround I was trying to get, fooling the TabBar that the controller changed, without actually being changed. Now I'm trying to figure how can I show the popover.